# Get Android Filing System root

Tags: android, filesystems

Is there ever more than one root of the Android filing system (for example with SD cards, or hidden partitions, or emulated files and folders, or similar)? The docs suggest not - https://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/File#listRoots()

I get the root like this:

```
File[] roots = File.listRoots();
String rootPath = "";
try {
    rootPath = roots[0].getCanonicalPath();
} catch (IOException e) {
    // do something
}
```

Is that really correct? Can I skip that and just assume '/' on Android if I want to address all the files in the device?

NB This seems to be different from getRootDirectory despite the similar name - https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment#getRootDirectory()

NB 2 this is part of my attempt to find a solution to [Crawling Android File System gets stuck in possible SymLink loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59559016/crawling-android-file-system-gets-stuck-in-possible-symlink-loop), so can be seen in that context if needed.

Comment: I'm trying to examine the linked post from first principles, to make sure that I haven't made any bad assumptions.